# Is it possible to abstract away the subject type in the declare parents statement?

Tags: aspectj

Consider the following abstract aspect:

```
public abstract aspect LoggingAspect {
  declare parents: (@LogMe *) implements ILoggable;

  ...
}
```

Is it possible to abstract `(@LogMe *)` away, behind a type pattern declaration, that could be overridden in a derived aspect?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can think of is to do something like this:

1. keep the abstract LoggingAspect as is
2. in the concrete sub-aspects use `declare @type` to add the `@LogMe` annotation where you need it to go.